# Integrate drag and drop functionality into Aloha Editor HTML5

Tags: drag-and-drop, aloha-editor

i'm using the Aloha Editor for my school project and i would like if someone could help me to integrate the drag'n drop functionality into the project. I have found this [**page**](http://aloha-editor.org/guides/plugin_block.html) but they are not specific in their explanations because i don't know where to put some code lines.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to bind the query `drop` event with the editable once it has been created. Then your callback will be called when something is dropped it in the editable.

```
$(function(){
    Aloha.bind('aloha-editable-created', function(event, editable){
        var the_obj = editable.obj;
        $(editable.obj).bind('drop', function(event){
             alert('something dropped in my editable');
        });
    });
})
```

I hope it helps